# How do I check which recovered files are valid?

Tags: linux, find, data-recovery

I have a lot of recovered files of which many are invalid even though they appear to be ok by name and extension. This is expected.

Now I to need filter out those which are probably ok. I see to options:

For example, power point files (*.pptx) are actually zip containers that start with PK in the first two bytes. So the command

```
head --byte 2 filename
```

outputs PK for most of the good files whereas the bad files don't start with PK.

**Question 1: How can I combine `head` with `find` to list out the files that match?**

Another approach is the `file` command. It prints

```
Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

for good power point files but simply

```
data
```

for bad files.

**Question 2: How can I combine `file` with `find` to list out valid files?**

There are also other file type but I can augment the technque if I only get the clue :)

**Question 3: Are the more obvious ways to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the `-printf` parameter to `find` that makes many things much easier than using `-exec`. So this command will identify the (probably) good files and move them into a subdirectory called good:

```
find . -type f -printf "file '%p' | grep 'Zip archive data' && mv '%p' good \n" | sh
```

For Word and Excel documents you can use the string "Author:" as valid doc files seem to have this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

With find you could do something like

```
find . -type f -exec file "{}" + | awk  '/Zip archive data/ {print $1}' | sed 's/:$//'
```

which will print the filename (removing the trailing :) of files that file identifies as `Zip archive` data.

Comment: Thanks! awk is also a good solution, however I have found the -printf parameter to make things quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using grep, since it is ment for searching for text in a file.

I am not certain of the particulars you will need, but this should get you started: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm

Comment: I know grep quite well, but I can't find an option to anchor the expression to the beginning of the file, only the beginning of line (the ^ operator).